# android imageview got distortion after being completely downloaded

Tags: android

As you all see in attachment, android imageview got distortion after being completely downloaded with using coding of following link [Load images from web and caching](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-load-images-from-web-and-caching/).

here is my imageview tag and original image resolution is 850x315.

```
   <ImageView
       android:paddingTop="10dip"
       android:paddingBottom="5dip"
       android:id="@+id/idThumb"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="70dp"
       android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
       android:scaleType="centerCrop"
       android:src="@drawable/no_image" />
```

Please check me why this ImageView cannot fetch original resolution of image from URL and got blur.![image]

Comment: Are the words supposed to be cut off like that? You can try scaletype="fitXY"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gotta use WebView instead of ImageView will fulfilled what I want.